# how can get checked box value in angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs

```
when checked checkbox  get checkbox value in angular js how can do please help me any one, i teken code from js fiddle add css and removed boostrap.
```

I am trying to display checked checkbox vlaues in my project how can do.please help me any once. I tryed that code i kept in js fiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/ramesh_bogandla/22et6sao/871/" please help me any one

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    var output = "";
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
        output += $(this).next('span').text() + ", ";
    }); 
    $(".textboxclass here").val(output.trim().slice(0,-1));  
});
```

Try It Once this is an example code for idea.

Comment: after check box that value must be in a span then that script takes next span text and it shows on your searchfield

Answer (score 0):

Check edited fiddle, just use `{{example14model}}` or more detailed access to this variable in template

https://jsfiddle.net/22et6sao/872/

Comment: here displaying array object , but i want to display vlaue how?

Comment: array of objects is your value. What do you want to display?

Comment: i want display checked chebox value or name

Comment: you can use idProp: 'label' in your component extra-settings